# How to use protection setWarningOnly(warningOnly) in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I saw google developers release Note here.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/
at August 4, 2015 they say "Added the following methods to the Spreadsheet service to let scripts control "warning-based" protection for spreadsheet ranges "

*Protection.isWarningOnly()
*Protection.setWarningOnly(warningOnly)

Im trying to make warning based protection sheet with google apps script.(and it should be have some unprotected cells)

i tried like this but it doesn't work.

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Sample protected sheet').isWarningOnly()
 var unprotected = sheet.getRange('B2:C5');
 protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotected]);
 protection.setWarningOnly(warningOnly)
```

does anyone success to use warningOnly methods?
please tell me how to use this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways to implement this. If you'd like to just set the protection value of a cell, you can use the following:

```
function warningOnly() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  // setWarningOnly is a boolean value, which means you have to set
  // it in the code as true or false.
  cell.protect().setWarningOnly(true);
}
```

If you have sheets with protected ranges and you want to change them to include a warning, you can run a quick test of the cell to find out:

```
function addNewWarning() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Test to see if a cell has a range protected already
  // If it is protected, remove the old rule and add the warning.
  // If it's not protected already, skip it.

  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)
  for(var i=0;i<protections.length;i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];

    // If it's protected and you can edit, remove it and add a warning.
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
      protection.remove();
      protection.getRange().protect().setWarningOnly(true);
      Logger.log("Warning added");
    } else {
      Logger.log("Not protected, no warning added");
    }
  }
}
```

I can't find a way to change the warning message, but it gets the behavior you're looking for. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help!Now i understand how setWarningOnly works! you are right, it needed to set "true" ! again thank you so much!